# How to periodically post random content as user to their wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Hello friends i have developed game application on facebook. I have to post random content as user to their wall at any time and automatically. Please suggest me the ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a thread that would do posting in periods. With respect to time that this thread would do the posting you could generate random values ​​(in Java http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62). These random values ​​were used in the thread sleep. to randomly generate the content, could use the same method as above. To do this, could use a java Map (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the keys are possible values ​​generated by the random method and the values ​​of the map would be the posting to be done.

To post in wall using Java:  http://restfb.com/